# Howto Install Gapps on Galaxy J3 Pro Plus j3119s?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-j3

I Have reset my phone and lost gapps
Does anyone know how to install gapps on  j3119s ?

I've tried everything but seems it doesn't work in this device

1. open gapps (flash from twrp)
2. gapps-5.1.x-20150404-minimal-edition-signed from XDA (flash from twrp)
3. google installer (ussualy work on xioami china  ROM)
4. etc

I'm really frustated, help really appreciated...

Comment: Have you lost PlayStore and Play Services as well?

Answer (score 1):

One of my friend had the same issue in past, and ii resolved this issue by flashing new Firmware (The reliable and trusted solution). I have made a rough search for you and found following link with detailed instructions:

https://4frp.blogspot.com/2017/09/sm-j3119511-lollipopandroid-august-08-17.html

in case you have nay difficulty in process, let me know.

Before proceeding with the solution, download Samsung drivers from their official website from here and install.

http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
SM-J3119 is different from my SM-J3119s, i saw it on many thread